# How to test a Wi-Fi device

Tags: product-testing, wifi

Usually, when testing a communication protocol, (for example emotion tests for TUV or CE) I use a test setup suggested by the standard organization.

I am looking for a similar test procedure for testing Wi-Fi devices TX/RX functionality in both, design stage and mass production. Is there a similar procedure. If not, where can I find an alternative testing set-up?